# Conditional records count with MDX, SQL Server BI

Tags: count, conditional-statements, ssas, mdx

This may be a simple MDX question but I've spent 2 days without any luck.

I have a simple fact table with the following columns:

```
ID        state        type        price
```

---

```
001        CA          TRUCK       50300
002        MA          BIKE        3010
003        MA          BOAT        0
004        CO          BOAT        20100
...        ...
```

I have a cube with 2 dimensions, state and type. Now I'd like to get a count of rows for these two dimensions where price > 0. Can I do it without creating a 3rd dimension (id)? How would I go about doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create a new column in your fact table/view -> CountRows which is 1 where the Price is > 0 and NULL otherwise. E.g. (in T-SQL):

```
...
CASE
    WHEN Price > 0 THEN 1
    ELSE NULL
END CountRows
...
```

Then, create a new measure with Sum aggregation type on top of this column and you should be good to go. In the example above, this new measure will give you 1 for State.MA and for Type.Boat.

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing - creating a new dimension on ID works too but the performance was horrendous. I ended up creating a separate listing count table parallel to my fact table. But I like your approach better. Thanks!

Comment: I'd use count aggregation type instead of sum, should be quicker.

Comment: It wouldn't matter if it is a Sum or a column-bound Count. They are both fully additive and there should be no difference in their performance.